# Android Telephony.Sms API read/write/delete all SMS records not just Sent and Inbox

Tags: android, sms

Working on an Android app that retreives SMS messages on the device using this code;

```
    public void refreshSmsSent() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    arrayAdapter.clear();
    Cursor c = contentResolver.query(Telephony.Sms.Sent.CONTENT_URI, // Official CONTENT_URI from docs
            new String[] { Telephony.Sms.Sent.ADDRESS, Telephony.Sms.Sent.BODY, Telephony.Sms.Sent._ID, Telephony.Sms.Sent.ERROR_CODE, Telephony.Sms.Sent.TYPE }, // Select body text
            null,
            null,
            Telephony.Sms.Sent.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER); // Default sort order
    int totalSMS = c.getCount();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < totalSMS; i++) {
            String str = "To: " + c.getString(0) +
                    "\n" + c.getString(1) + "\n" + c.getString(2) + "\n" + c.getString(3) + "\n" + c.getString(4) + "\n";
            arrayAdapter.add(str);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    } else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing here..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    c.close();
}
```

This works absolutely fine for `Telephony.Sms.Sent` and `Telephony.Sms.Inbox` but I can't seem to get anything back using the same code with `Telephony.Sms.Outbox` or `Telephony.Sms.Draft`

I think I have the required permissions in place in the manifest;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Question: 
Ideally, I'd like to get all SMS records on the device and process (e.g. delete, resend) each one in my own code... is there a method I can use to retrieve all SMS messages on the device in one go using a single query..?

A day later... some progress... this code using `Telephony.Sms` gets all Sent and Inbox entries in single query...

```
    public void refreshSmsAll() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    arrayAdapter.clear();
    Cursor c = contentResolver.query(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI, // Official CONTENT_URI from docs
            new String[] { Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS, Telephony.Sms.BODY, Telephony.Sms.TYPE, Telephony.Sms.ERROR_CODE, Telephony.Sms._ID }, // Select body text
            null,
            null,
            Telephony.Sms.Draft.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER); // Default sort order
    int totalSMS = c.getCount();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < totalSMS; i++) {
            String str = "X: " + c.getString(0) +
                    "\n" + c.getString(1) + "\n" + c.getString(2) + "\n" + c.getString(3) + "\n" + c.getString(4) + "\n";
            arrayAdapter.add(str);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    } else {
Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing here..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    c.close();
}
```

However, what it doesn't get is Outbox and Draft... any ideas, anyone..?

Another 2hrs later... getting somewhere with the delete now...

```
    public void onDeleteMsg(View view) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    boolean isSmsDeleted = false;
    try {
        contentResolver.delete(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI, "_id=?",new String[] { "371" });
        isSmsDeleted = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Deleted..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        isSmsDeleted = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "NOT Deleted..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Only works if my sms app is the default, which is fine, so that means I have to insert and delete messages in the sms database myself..!

```
    public void onInsertMsg(View view) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS, "123456789");
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.BODY, "The message");
    values.put(Telephony.Sms.TYPE, "2");
    boolean isSmsDeleted = false;
    try {
        contentResolver.insert(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI,values);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inserted..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "NOT Inserted..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Scenario: 
Along with plenty of received/sent sms, I've created a draft message and forced a failed message to a dud number, neither of which appear in any query.

Interestingly, if I force a manual re-send on the failed message it appears in the Sent query for the duration of the re-try, then it isn't present.

I'm assuming that anything I can see in the standard messaging app for the device should be available to my "home-made" app, understanding that there may be some limitations depending on which one is the default SMS app.

Comment: Are you sure that drafts are saved in the Device database? I think they are saved only withing the app that manages SMS

Comment: Disregard last comment, the documentation likely says they are stored.

Comment: Thanks for your interest  @Vladyslav-Matviienko Yeah, I was presuming they are all in the same data record but just have a different TYPE

Comment: Starting with Marshmallow, non-default apps can view only sent and inbox messages. Only the default app has access to the other types.

Comment: Thanks @mike-m I get that now, still can't seem to retrieve Outbox and Draft, thought they would come back with Inbox an sent. Strange!

Answer (score 0):

you are using the wrong classes to fetch sms.

If you have to use these classes to fetch relevant information :

```
Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI - For Inbox message
Telephony.Sms.Sent.CONTENT_URI - For sent messages .
```

Reference : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.

My Github code for fetching Inbox SMSs :
https://github.com/meajay/SampleSmsApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/assignment/com/smsapplication/utils/SmsAPI.java